# How to configure and run old php 5.4 web application in docker with mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, docker

I have an old application based on php 5.4 and mysql. I had developed that in 2015. I want to run that application using docker as changing php version for individual application is not a feasible solution.

What I did is as follows:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:5.4-apache

COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY . /var/www/html/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html

    # first load the 'db' service
    depends_on:
    - db
    links:
      - db

  db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      restart: always
      ports:
      - "13306:3306"
      environment:
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: admin
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
        MYSQL_DATABASE: pizzabite
      volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

The problem here is I was accessing mysql using old mysql methods i.e mysql_connect() etc.

**database.php**

```
<?php
// Connecting to the database server
$servername = "localhost:13306";
$username = "root";
$password = "admin";
$port = "13306";
$dbname = "pizzabite";


$connect = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("<br/>Check your server connection...");

//  $connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname,$port); // I do not want to use mysqli_* function

$selectedDB = mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysqli_error());
//include('date.php');
?>
```

This file is included everywhere using `include()` but when run using docker this file gives error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/database.php on line 10

Check your server connection...
```

When using **0.0.0.0:13306** it gives me this error:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): Connection refused in /var/www/html/database.php on line 10

Check your server connection...
```

**`docker-compose ps` command output:**

```
      Name                       Command               State                 Ports               
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pizza_corner_db_1       docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      0.0.0.0:13306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
pizza_corner_webapp_1   /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOR ...   Up      0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp
```

Comment: You can try replace `$servername = "localhost:13306";` to `$servername = "db:13306";`

Comment: @Dmitry same issue

Comment: I found solution you need use the `db:3306` because you try connect inside the docker

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to connect to `localhost:13306`, because your PC port `13306` is forwarded to the mysql container.

However, that code is executed from the `php-apache` container, so 'localhost' is the container, not your pc. There is no port `13306` available there.

You should connect to `db:13306` because in your docker-compose the database container is called `db`.

Also, be sure to enable mysql in your php container:

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql && docker-php-ext-enable mysql
```

Comment: Thanks but still same issue :connection refused. I down the containers, built it and up the containers. Anything else I need to do ?

Comment: Maybe use the 3306 port instead of 13306, considering you are not connecting using your pc host anymore

Comment: That did the trick, I used db:3306 and it was running. but why using 3306 instead of 13306 ?

Comment: Using ports `13306:3306` you tell docker: every request coming into port 13306 of my PC host should be forward to port 3306 of the database container. howevery, when making a request from the php container, your request goes 'directly' to the container, not to your pc host, so you should use the port of the container (3306) and not the port of your pc host (13306)

Comment: Thank you a lot for explaining the things. You made my day.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for docker command to install and enable PHP MySQL extension